# htaccess http to https redirecting to REWRITE but appending php GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My http to https redirect is 301 redirecting but it is including the appending PHP from the Rewrite Rule.  For example:

http://www.testsite.com/staff/james/ is redirecting to https://www.testsite.com/staff/?hookName=james

Here is my https redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

My rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^/staff/(.*)/$ staff.php?hookName=$1
```

On my PHP page, I can obviously 301 it to the correct link.  However, I'm trying to stop it from happening in the first place so I don't have a double 301.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^/staff/(.*)/$ staff.php?hookName=$1`

Comment: Did you put your redirect rule _before_ rewrite rule?

Comment: I tried moving it, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your case, placing the internal rewrite under the external redirect will fix the problem. Please note that since you used a 301 redirect, the browser might have cached the old redirect, completely bypassing the server. Either use a different url you haven't tried before, try it in a different browser you haven't tested in before, or clear your cache. In the future, I would recommend turning all redirects into 302 (or temporary) redirects until you have thoroughly tested that everything works as expected.

Comment: @GarethHanda `301` responses are cached by all modern browsers (especially Chrome or Firefox) .. so clear browser cache and restart your browser is a must here. That's why it's better to test with `302` first and then turn into proper `301` later after testing is done.